Import key-vault reference azure app settings
I'm using portal to import JSON file which contains key-value pairs. Need help in importing key-valult references.
I prepare a json file like
{
  AppSettings: {
     "testKey": "testValue",
     "testSecrete": "<akv-Reference-TestSecreteKey>"
   }
}

what should I add in place "akv-Reference-TestSecreteKey", so that when I import this file it add as key-vault reference.
While Import I choose:

Type: Configuration File
Code: .Net


I tried this
{
    "AppSettings": {        
        "Test": "testValue",
            "TestSceret": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=
https://xyz.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretValue/)"
    }
}

But it added as key-value, with value same as @Microsoft.KeyVault(S...

Are you trying this locally?This works only in Azure App Service.

Yes, I'm picking the file from my local

Key reference works only for the deployed app

What is the content type you are using?

I was not selecting any content type, but realized later it should be 'application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.keyvaultref+json;charset=utf-8' with some changes in value(updated in the ans).

Found the answer from my colleague, we need to separate our json file from regular keys, and key vault secrets.
key vault secret json will look like
{
    "AppSettings": {        
        "testKey": "{\"uri"\: \"https://xyz.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretValue/")"
    }
}

And while importing there will be different contentType something like 'application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.keyvaultref+json;charset=utf-8'.
This will add key as keyvault reference.

Try it using the actual SecretName -
{
    "AppSettings": {        
        "testValue": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://xyz.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretValue/)"
    }
}

According to Import or export configuration data
, you might need to change your Content-Type as per below:
Content type    Optional. Indicate if you're importing a JSON file or Key Vault references. For more information about Key Vault references, go to Use Key Vault references in an ASP.NET Core app.

I was doing with actual secret, but @harshita said in question's comment, could it be due to local machine I'm importing?

@harpal Please find updated answer.

@harpal - Ignore my comment it will not work locally...It is for azure app service

You can use a Key Vault reference in form @Microsoft.KeyVault({referenceString})
Example:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)

Alternatively:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)

Please note that you need to grant your app access to a key vault.
See also Troubleshooting key vault references.

I tried that, but it added same as key-value.

@harpal updated my answer - forgot to mention you need to grant your app access to the keyvault.

App has access there are many secrets and keys already, I'm facing issue when uploading file from my local machine through azure portal.
